# How to obfuscate fields, but keep "setField" format for setters and getters in Proguard?

Tags: java, proguard

I'm using ORMLite in my project when working with database and I need it to use setters and getters for the fields of the database class. So when I mark a field like so:

```
@DatabaseField(useGetSet = true)
private String name;
```

It starts looking for `setName()` and `getName()` methods respectively. However, when I obfuscate with Proguard, the `name` may become `a`, but `setName()` and `getName()` will become, say, `b()` and `c()`. I want them to become `setA()` and `getA()`.

Is that possible?

The only workaround I see right now is keeping the whole class intact (I can't use access via reflection, because I do additional stuff to the fields in the setter).

Comment: This is topic is covered in detail in the [examples section](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/examples). Better advice would be to get rid of proguard - it's a pointless waste of time that adds no security and any half capable engineer with a decent IDE can reverse engineer trivially.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I am aware of that. However, that is not my decision. If you're talking about [this](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/examples#beans) example, then I've seen it.